# OpenGL Texture Discoloration in iOS7

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, ios7

I pulled out the latest beta version of Xcode 5 with iOS7 Beta 5 to check compatibility with one of my apps that uses OpenGL ES 2.0. Upon launching my app in the new simulator, I was greeted with a very discolored screen. Not to say the whole screen was discolored, only the GLView. Reds had turned blue, blues had turned blue-er, and greens were tinted blue.

I've searched up and down google with no results even coming close. Below is a rendering of a football field to show the discoloration. It's especially noticeable with the track and field goals.

GL Enabled options

```
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = true;
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);//Only when drawing field goals
```

How it should look (iOS6)

[image]

How it looks now (iOS7)

[image]

Comment: DavidRönnqvist: No. Should I?
@JoshCaswell: I'm confused by your comment. I posted this because I was simply hoping to find an answer, and I did :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must have been a change in the way GLKit handles texture loading in iOS7. I replaced several of these textures with simple, single layer PNGs and there was no issue.
As a work around, I was able to export each texture from the PSD to TIFF format with no discoloration or loss of image quality. TIFFs seem to be the way to go; GLKit has no issues with the format and it happily supports transparency which oddly enough was another issue that I ran into with discoloration.

```
texturename = tracktexture1.name;
glDeleteTextures(1, &texturename);
tracktexture1 = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i",trackname, 1] ofType:@"tiff"] options:options error:&error];
```